# Write XSL template for a nested node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML structure which is a simplified version of a big XML and I need to write an XSL template to get the data from a specific node (Dimensions).

I already have an XSL to do the transformation. There is a new node `<Dimensions>` that is added and it can occur multiple times inside a node as shown below. I need to read the data from `general/electronics/tv/description/Dimensions` and output its content (`div` tag content) into the resulting HTML output. The `<Dimensions>` can also occur under the `software/version/description/Dimensions` node or any other node.

**So my question is:**
Is there a generic way to write a template which can read the contents of the `<Dimensions>` tag and output its contents? I need some help in writing the XSL template for this tag.

```html
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <DVD>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </DVD>
  <DVD>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </DVD>
  <general>
   <electronics>
    <tv>
     <name>samsung</name>
     <model>2.1</model>
    </tv>
    <tv>
     <name>vizio</name>
     <model>2.1</model>
     <description>
      <span>PurColor: Enjoy millions of shades of color, fine tuned to create an incredibly vibrant picture</span>
      <Dimensions> <div>3.6 width</div></Dimensions>
      <span>Enjoy subtle details hidden in the shadows of color and darkness with precise lighting that reveals a lifelike picture.</span>
      <Dimensions><div>4.8 height<div></Dimensions>
     </description>
    </tv>
   </electronics>
  </general>
  <software>
   <version>
     <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
     <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
     <country>UK</country>
     <company>CBS</company>
     <price>8.10</price>
     <year>1973</year>
     <description>
     <span>Electric water kettle with 1.0-liter capacity and 1500 watts of power for fast results (120V ~60Hz)</span>
     <Dimensions> <div>5.6 width</div></Dimensions>
     <span>cordless design allows for easy filling and serving; power base with 30-inch power cord for flexible placement, plus cord wrap for compact storage.</span>
     <Dimensions><div>5.8 height</div></Dimensions>
    </description>
    <version>
  </software>
 
</catalog>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the desired element's node with the XPath expression

```
/catalog/general/electronics/tv/description/Dimensions
```